# Regex match for text between two anchors

Tags: java, regex

I need a RegEx that would only target the items listed in the following example:

```
The category: 
A short description about the following list:
Item 1, Located at Place 1
Item 2, Located at Place 2
Item 3, Located at Place 3
The next category:
```

I can match everything after "The category" and before "The next category:", but I cannot only get the items. The example description will change from document to document.

This will be used with Java, but I'd prefer to have a pure regex example if possible.

I've been working on this for hours and I'm pulling my hair out. Help is vastly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the small description always ends with a colon and that there are no other colons in the string within the items, you could maybe use something like this:

```
The category:\\s*[^:]*:\\s*([^:]*)\\s+The next category:
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hI7oJ5)

`[^:]*` matches any character except colons. `\\s+` is for newlines. The rest of the regex is pretty literal otherwise.

Comment: he will have random names of categories

Comment: @aelor OP mentioned: 'The example **description** will change from document to document'. There was no mention of the category, and OP already mentioned 'I can match everything after "The category" and before "The next category:"', so those two have to be literal.

Comment: @Jerry - this is almost exactly what I need. Your regex example is coming up as two matches: (1) the whole text sample, and (2) the specific list within the whole text sample. Is there way for only the second part to match? Thanks!

Comment: @TinActon Sorry, I forgot that Java's regex doesn't support some other features that Perl or C# does and as such, I don't know of a method to match the list alone :(

Comment: @TinActon If you use `matcher.group(1)`, there shouldn't be any issue (I think). Something a bit like [this](http://ideone.com/KZc0Rx).

Comment: @Jerry Ah! That example will help because some documents have more than one of these, up to 5 or 6, and some just have 1. I can probably just pick the odd numbered matcher.group(). Thanks again, this has been a huge relief. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regex for this.  Write a simple parser:

```
var lines = text.split('\n');

var category     = '',
    categoryLine = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    if (/category:$/.test(line)) {
        // beginning of a new category
        category = line;
        categoryLine = i;
        console.log('BEGIN CATEGORY: ' + line);
    } else if (i == categoryLine + 1) {
        // description line (skip)
    } else {
        // this is an item in a list
        console.log('category="%s" item="%s"',
            category, line);
    }
}
```

Assumptions:

- Category lines always end with `category:`
- Each category has a description line after it
- All other lines are items

Comment: How do you know the OP wants this in JavaScript?